# READYSTATE never get the COMPLETED state

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

The below macro works in IE9, but when using IE11 it stops on the `Do While` statement. Also, `Set HTMLDoc = ie.document` does not work for the same reason.

Note that the website will not work as it is restricted to some users only.

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetHTMLDocument()

Dim ie As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLInput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim htmlbuttons As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim htmlbutton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement


ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "siiprodsrs01.db.sma"

Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Loop


Set HTMLDoc = ie.document

Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("what")
HTMLInput.Value = "12345"

Set htmlbuttons = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("button")

For Each htmlbutton In htmlbuttons
Debug.Print htmlbutton.className, htmlbutton.tagName, htmlbutton.ID, htmlbutton.innerText

Next htmlbutton

htmlbuttons(0).Click

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with IE is that the READYSTATE never get the COMPLETED state during the do while, it happened to me many time, reading online seem to be a IE problem,

Sometime this helped me

```
Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop
```

An alternative are to declare IE object with event and use the ie_documentComplete event:

```
Option Explicit
'Requires Microsoft Internet Controls Reference Library
Dim WithEvents ie As InternetExplorer
Sub start_here()
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = True
    'First URL to go, next actions will be executed in
    'Webbrowser event sub procedure - DocumentComplete
    ie.Navigate "siiprodsrs01.db.sma"
End Sub

Private Sub ie_DocumentComplete(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant)
    'pDisp is returned explorer object in this event
    'pDisp.Document is HTMLDocument control that you can use
    Set HTMLDoc = pDisp.Document
    'Since there is no do-loop, we have to know where we are by using some reference
    If InStr(1, URL, "siiprodsrs01.db.sma") > 0 Then
        Set HTMLInput = pdDisp.document.getElementById("what")
        HTMLInput.Value = "12345"

        Set htmlbuttons = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("button")

        For Each htmlbutton In htmlbuttons
            Debug.Print htmlbutton.className, htmlbutton.tagName, htmlbutton.ID, 
            htmlbutton.innerText
        Next htmlbutton

        htmlbuttons(0).Click

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice one! How do I make this to work with multiple tabs that I want to access elements from different domains - just add another case to the IF block?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The macro is not running because of declaring  `Dim WithEvents ie As InternetExplorer`. It shows in red when I want to run the macro even though I already ticked Microsoft internet controls in references. Appreciate you your time

Comment: @Dawood, did you referenced the Microsoft Internet Controls?

Comment: @PatricK this event is fired everytime the ie object load completely the dom, atm 2 solutions come to my mind, one is to ad another if block like you said, but you have to change the same ie instance to the second url, or create another instance of InternetExplorer named differently (maybe ie2) and create a second sub named ex:
ie2_DocumentComplete(ByVal pDisp as Object, URL as Variant)

Comment: yes, I did. And, when I put `WithEventsie` without space it moved forward but stopped at `Set ie = New InternetExplorer` and says variable not define

Comment: @Dawood https://prnt.sc/gju21t look at this, make sure that when you write "Dim WithEvents ie as Int...." you will get the intellisense saying "InternetExplorer"

Comment: @exSnake, I typed it `Dim WithEventsie As InternetExplorer` without space and removed the `Open explicit`; it opened the website but did not enter the value. However, it won't work when I make them separate like  prnt.sc/gju21t

Comment: @exSnake I think you have to put `Dim WithEvents ie As InternetExplorer` in a Class Module? Error "Only valid in object module" if the **Dim WithEvents** put in normal module.

Comment: sorry, it does not work and I'm looking for a solution to this problem.

Comment: There is two solution, the easiest is for look at page and wait for some element to load in a while loop, if it's loaded that mean IE exited the Readystate uncomplete. The second one is to use XMLHTTP or Winhttp library... without using IE

Comment: would you please type the full code for that and thank you in advance!